# Kendo UI Upload Send additional data on remove

Tags: c#, razor, upload, kendo-ui

I'm sending addition data when i use the remove button on upload component successfully. I am using single file mode. When I change the uploaded document, first, remove is called without additional data automatically then upload is called. I need this remove call sends the additional data,too. Hope, it is clear. Below is my razor code.

```
 <div class="form-group">
            @Html.Label("Attachments".Localize(), new { @class = "control-label col-sm-3" })
            @(Html.Kendo().Upload().Name("Attachments")
                .Async(a => a
                .Save("SaveAttachment", "Upload", new { Area = "" })
                .Remove("RemoveAttachment", "Upload", new { Area = "" })
                .AutoUpload(true)
                ).Multiple(false)
                .Messages(message =>
                {
                    message.Select("Select XSLT File");
                })
                .HtmlAttributes(new { accept = ".xslt" })
                .Events(events => events
                .Cancel("onCancel")
                .Complete("onComplete")
                .Remove(@<text>
                    function(e) {
                    e.data = { folderReference: $("#FolderReference").val() };
                    }
                </text>)
                .Select("onSelect")
                .Success("onSuccess")
                .Upload(@<text>
                    function(e) {
                    e.data = { folderReference: $("#FolderReference").val()};

                    }
                </text>)
                        )
            )
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue has been addressed in recent 2015 releases. Additional data set in the remove event handler will be send to the remove action along with the file names.